# jQuery selectable and checkall conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict

i have a question about checkall, there is a "selectable" method and "checkall" event in jQuery.

If I select two checkboxes below, it will be unchecked(above), but if I change the name of my "td", than it works.

```
(   cancel:'td:not(.**isaretle**)',)
```

Can you please help me?

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/xUU4p/1/

Comment: Frankly could not get what you want?

Comment: if i select checkbox1 and checkbox2, it must be "Check All" Checkbox selected. But here it works not.
-------------------------------------------

http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/xUU4p/9/

------------------------------------------------------------------------
But if i change the name of "isaretle" in jQuery, it works very well.
This time "the selectable" method works not. i want to both (checkall and selectable)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.checkAll').live('change', function () {
            var self = $(this),
                isChecked = self.is(':checked'),
                checked = isChecked ? 'checked' : '',
                text = isChecked ? 'Uncheck All' : 'Check All';
            $('.chc').attr('checked', checked);
            self.next().text(text);
        });
        $('.chc').live('change', function () {
            var chcLen = $('.chc').length,
                checkedLen = $('.chc:checked').length,
                lenMatches = chcLen === checkedLen,
                checked = lenMatches ? 'checked' : '',
                text = lenMatches ? 'Uncheck All' : 'Check All';
            $('.checkAll').attr('checked', checked).next().text(text);
        });
        $("#slctble").selectable({
            "filter": "td:not(.isaretle)",
            "stop": function () {
                $(".ui-selected input", this).each(function () {
                    this.checked = !this.checked;
                }); //end-ui-selected input
            } //endStopFunction
        }); //endSelectable
    }); //endWindowsLoad
}(jQuery.noConflict())); //end Function
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xUU4p/28/